# Creating Popups or Notifications

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I was looking through the Consumer and Admin API documents and couldn't find anything on creating popups or notifications. Do we as developers have access to these kinds of features? Possibly to create a popup with an alert or a link to an external application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you're looking for is the Admin API's [Alerts](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/alerts/details/) endpoint.

However, bear in mind that the endpoint is not *guaranteed* to send a *push* notification. The user can set their own preferences (e.g. push, SMS, email) for notification channels for the alert configuration (see the Consumer API's [Alerts](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/alerts/details/) counterpart).